# Binding dropdownlist without causing postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have two textboxes, ID and Name. Based on the combination of these two, my address dropdown should get populated.
I have written an sp to bind items to my dropdown. But the text_changed event of Name textbox causes AutoPostback. I want my dropdownlist to bind automatically when I leave the textbox without causing any refreshing of the page. On page load all 3 should be blank.

Please let me know how to accomplish this using javascript and jquery.
Please excuse for any typing mistakes.

Comment: some code or your efforts would be useful

Comment: use ajax its comes very handy for such kinda problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either user jQuery Ajax or UpdatePanel

Using JQuery Ajax...

```
$.ajax({
       data: data,
       url: "ur url",
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function (result) {
       //ur code to bind data to dropdown
       }
       error: function OnError(result) {
        //ur code
       }
    });
```

Using Update Panel you can call server side method to bind data to dropdown

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" OnTextChanged="txtBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks...though there is no refreshing/reloading of page as I am using Ajax, but the dropdown takes time to load, even if there are 2 records. Any siggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Frankly speaking 2 or 10 records doesnot matter unless the no is too large. You need to check the code u have written. Ideally its fast.